# How commonly is "but" used in sentences?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

Usually, whenever I post a question on Stack Overflow, I have a habit of using the word *but* excessively.  Is there an alternative word can I use?

Comment: @user your title provides a different question than your text.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use these:

- However
- Although
- On the other hand (can also be used together with "but")
- Unfortunately
- Nevertheless
- Still
- Though
- Yet
- Except
- Unless

You can see more synonyms [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/but?&submit=Go) (from an online thesaurus).

Comment: great list for other words.

Answer (score 3):

**Frequency**

"but" is used about 1 in every 400 words, at least in books.

[image]

**Synonyms**

From [wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/thesaurus/but)

> ac  ·  although  ·  bar  ·  besides  ·
> boundary  ·  except  ·  excepting  ·
> excluding  ·  further  ·  howbeit  ·
> however  ·  howsoever  ·  howsomever
> ·  limit  ·  merely  ·  more  ·
> moreover  ·  natheless  ·  nathless  ·
> nevertheless  ·  notwithstanding  ·
> only  ·  save  ·  solely  ·  still  ·
> unless  ·  with the exception of  ·
> without  ·  yet

Comment: great list for other words.

Answer (score 0):

'though' is a pretty common synonym, but it goes at the end of the phrase generally.
'however' is another. it can be used before or after.

Comment: Though "though" is sometimes used at the end, it can also be used at the beginning :-)

Comment: hence 'generally'. ;) Used at the beginning of the sentence it is not as directly interchangeable with 'but', though. I'd have to reorder my clauses.